# Не запускается парсер selenium в терминале

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium

Ранее запускал код на другой системе, ничего не добавлял, гекодрайвер был на месте и путь прописан. По итогу selenium выдает

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip")
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",f"{os.getcwd()}")
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled",True)
service = Service(f"{os.getcwd()}/firefoxdriver/geckodriver")
url = ''
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, firefox_profile=firefoxProfile, options=options)
```

Использую selenium 4.6.0 на системе установлен firefox

Comment: проверьте версию веб-драйвера, потом браузера сначала. они должны соотвествовать.

Comment: не помогло вообще

Comment: ну ок, выключаем headless. проверяем каждую строку, переустанавливаем selenium

Comment: попробуйте переписать на remotewebdriver